# StackOverflowError with JPA bidirectional references in Kotlin

Tags: java, jpa, kotlin, stack-overflow, bidirectional

I have data classes as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECTIONS")
data class Section(

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "ID")
        var id: Long = 0,

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        var name: String = "",

        @OneToMany(
                mappedBy = "section",
                fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
                cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL),
                orphanRemoval = true
        )
        var fields: MutableList<Field> = mutableListOf()
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "FIELDS")
data class Field(

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "ID")
        var id: Long = 0,

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        var name: String = "",

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "SECTION_ID")
        var section: Section? = null
)
```

As you can see, there is a bidirectional mapping between Section and Field. When I create a Section object, a Field object and I add the Field object to the list of fields in the Section object, it works fine. However, when I also set the Field's section reference to the Section object and then persist, I get a StackOverflowError:

```
@Test
fun testCascadeSaving() {
    val section = Section(name = "Section 1")
    val field = Field(name = "Field 1")

    section.fields.add(field)
    field.section = section

    val savedSection = sectionRepository.save(section)
    val savedField = savedSection.fields[0]

    // This causes an StackOverflowError
    val f = fieldRepository.findOne(savedField.id)
}
```

I have to comment the *field.section = section* line in order for the code above to work properly.

Any ideas why setting bidirectional relationship causes this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've actually managed to solve the problem - all I've had to do was to override the *toString()* method in at least one of the entities. The implementations provided by Kotlin included calling each other's *toString()* methods recursively thus resulting in *StackOverflowError*.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FIELDS")
data class Field(

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "ID")
        var id: Long = 0,

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        var name: String = "",

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "SECTION_ID")
        var section: Section? = null
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Field(id=$id, name=$name)"
    }
}
```